# replicating dplyr quote and enquote examples

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

I am having a hard time replicating the examples in [dplyr.tidyverse.org]http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html.
Here is my code and session info. I've spent way too much time today chasing   after false leads, and re-installing packages. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
library(dplyr)  

 df <- tibble(  
 g1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
 g2 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1),
 a = sample(5), 
 b = sample(5)
)

my_summarise <- function(df, group_by) {
 group_by <- enquo(group_by)
 print(group_by)

 df %>%
  group_by_(!!group_by) %>%
  summarise(a = mean(a))
}

my_summarise(df, g1)
```

And here is the error I get:

```
Error in !group_by : invalid argument type  
Called from: compat_lazy_dots(.dots, caller_env(), ...)
```

Here is the session info:

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)  
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)  
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1  


Matrix products: default  

locale:  
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          

[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:  
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.7.4.9000     lubridate_1.5.6      pander_0.6.0         
RevoUtilsMath_10.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.11     digest_0.6.9     withr_1.0.2      assertthat_0.2.0 
R6_2.2.0         magrittr_1.5    
 [7] git2r_0.18.0     httr_1.2.1       stringi_1.1.5    rlang_0.1.2.9000 
curl_2.6         bindrcpp_0.2    
[13] devtools_1.12.0  RevoUtils_10.0.4 tools_3.4.0      stringr_1.2.0    
glue_1.1.1       compiler_3.4.0    
[19] pkgconfig_2.0.1  memoise_1.1.0    bindr_0.1        knitr_1.16       
tibble_1.3.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me. `group_by_` is deprecated, so please use `group_by`. By the way, you use `group_by` as an argument name for your function. I think this is a bad idea since `group_by` is a defined function in `dplyr`. You may want to consider changing this argument name to avoid confusion.

```
library(dplyr)  

df <- tibble(  
  g1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  g2 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1),
  a = sample(5), 
  b = sample(5)
)

my_summarise <- function(df, group_by) {
  group_by <- enquo(group_by)
  print(group_by)

  df %>%
    group_by(!!group_by) %>%
    summarise(a = mean(a))
}

my_summarise(df, g1) 
<quosure: global>
~g1
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     g1     a
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3
2     2     3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, to the point where the code ycw posted above gave the `invalid argument type`. It appeared to occur only in the session where I'd upgraded dplyr, once I'd started a fresh session the code ycw posted worked fine.